# how to select dynamic content loaded with .load()

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble selecting content that was loaded onto the page with .load()

I know I can bind events with `$('#container').on('click', '.item', function() { // do something });` instead of `$('#container .item')` but I am not having luck simply selecting these items.

index.html :

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

somefile.html :

```
<div class="item">one</div>
<div class="item">two</div>
```

jq/js :

```
$('#container').load('somefile.html');

$('.item').css('background', 'blue'); //not working

$('#container .item').css('background', 'blue'); //not working

var container = $(container);
$('.item', container).css('background', 'blue'); //not working
```

Comment: `.load()` is asynchronous

Comment: ah yes.  so i will do stuff within the complete function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, `.load()` is asynchronous, meaning you can't guarantee it will be complete when the subsequent instructions execute.

To fix this, run the code in a callback from `.load()`, which will only be called when the `.load()` completes:

```
$('#container').load('somefile.html', function() {
    $('.item').css('background', 'blue'); 
});
```

Comment: @asdfqwerzxcv, You got it. But Jeff answered before you get. I think it's fair if you upvote his answer and select it.

Comment: i had already commented that i will do stuff within the complete function so the answer wasn't necessary but ok

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question with thanks to the reminder from the comments..

`.load()` is asynchronous so don't try to select the content until after it has been loaded.  Use a callback 'complete' function.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#container').load('somefile.html', function() {
  $('.item').css('background', 'blue');
});
```